# Svelte - how to wait for data that is being passed in from parent component?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

I'm learning Svelte and I want to use data from one JSON API in three components. The data looks like this:

```json
{
  "stats": {
    "currentYear": {
      "total": 6,
      "success": 6
    },
    "thirty": {
      "total": 30,
      "success": 28
    },
    "hundred": {
      "total": 100,
      "success": 92
    },
    "allTime": {
      "total": 789,
      "success": 728
    }
  },
  "heatmap": {
     ...
  },
  "other": {
     ...
  }
}
```

I retrieve the data via `onMount` in the `App.svelte` main component via async fetch, this works well. Then I want to pass each object to its corresponding component, so the `stats` object gets passed to `Stats.svelte`, the `heatmap` object to `Heatmap.svelte` etc.

To illustrate my issue, in `Stats.svelte` I am trying to display percentage values for each time period, for example:

- current year: 100%
- last thirty days: 93%
- last 100 days: 92%
- all time: 92%

Also, the CSS class for each will be based on some threshold values to change the colour (x >= 95: green, 95 > x >= 90: yellow, x < 90: red).

So some basic computation is needed which I wanted to have in a generic function, like shown below.

The `stats` object does get passed in from the parent component `App.svelte`, and if all I wanted to do is to show its values in the HTML via the `{#await}` block, this would work fine.  However, I want to do some calculations, so I wanted to call a function that would use the `stats` object's data, but I do not know how to call this function at the right moment. Calling it on `onMount` does not work, because it's too early, the data coming in from the parent component has not yet been received.

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte"
    
    export let stats

    let currentYearClass, currentYearStat

    const calcPercentage = async (period) => {
        currentYearStat = stats[period].currentYearSuccess * 100 / stats[period].currentYearTotal
        currentYearClass = 'green'
    }

    onMount( async () => {
        calcPercentage('currentYear')
    })
</script>
<div id="stats">
{#await stats}
    <div>Waiting for stats ...</div>
{:then stats}
    <div class="{currentYearClass}" id="currentYear">{currentYearStat}</div>
    ...
    ...
{/await}
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but one way would be to have the `calcPercentage` take in the `stats` as an argument and then call it reactively.

```js
export let stats
let currentYearClass, currentYearStat

const calcPercentage = (stats, period) => {
   currentYearStat = stats[persion}......
   currentYearClass = 'green'
}

$: stats && calcPercentage(stats, 'currentYear')
```

**edit: some eplaining**

The first problem with the original solution, something you probably noticed is that the component is *mounted* without the correct data, making *stats* to be undefined.

The above solution works in two steps:

```js
$: stats && calcPercentage(stats, 'currentYear')
```

This first part defines a reactive statement, it will check if *stats* evaluates to true, something it will do unless it is undefined, false or 0.  If *stats* is true it will then execute the function.

The second part is a the same function as before, I added the *stats* argument here although it is strictly not required *in this situation*, as the function will, because of the earlier execute everytime *stats* changes and is a true-like value.

With those two in place, when mounting the reactive statement will fail because *stats* is undefined, the function is not executed. Once the data comes in, it will be re-evaluated, *stats* is no longer undefined and the function fires.

**extra**

When the reactive statement would be of the form:

```js
$: myfunction(myvar)
```

It will execute for *every value* change of myvar, even during the mounting (consider it going from non exisiting to undefined ?). This means you would have to move your check into the function itself, for some scenarios this might be desired, an example is where this actually part of an assignment and the function itself is defined outside the component

```js
import heavyCalc from 'heavy/calc/function`

$: value = heavyCalc(otherValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show how `stats` is passed down to this component, but we can extrapolate two problems from your original solution:

1. The `stats` prop isn't passed in right away, therefore `stats` is `undefined` during `onMount`.
2. `onMount` is only executed when a component is mounted to the DOM (see [documentation](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#onmount)). If `stats` changes during the lifetime of the component `calcPercentage` will not be rerun.

You're looking for a way to run `calcPercentage` *every time* `stats` changes. You should use a [reactive statement](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive) for this:

```js
$: if (stats) calcPercentage('currentYear')
```

This reactive statement will run *every time* `stats` changes.

The `if` ensures that `calcPercentage` only runs if `stats` has a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). `undefined` is *falsy*, so `calcPercentage` will not run as long as `stats` is `undefined`.
A more elegant (but less resilient) approach would be to only render your `Stats` component after the data has been loaded using [`{#await}`](https://svelte.dev/docs/logic-blocks#await), as described by [@Ayoub Fiad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77245803/10434371).

Please note that the Svelte compiler does **not** know that `calcPercentage` depends on `stats`, only values which directly appear within the reactive statement will become dependencies. In this case it knows to rerun when `stats` changes because `stats` is used directly in the `if`-block. The alternative for situations where you don't need such an `if` is to make `calcPercentage` take `stats` as a parameter, as described in [@Stephane Vanraes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65664865/10434371).

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose to render the `Stats.svelte` component only after the data is loaded using [`{#await}`](https://svelte.dev/docs/logic-blocks#await):

1. In `App.svelte` do this:

   ```html
   {#await promise}

       <div>Loading...<div>

   {:then stats}

       <Stats {stats} />

   {/await}
   ```
2. In `Stats.svelte` your data will be ready to use.

Comment: This approach makes a lot of sense! OP should also make sure that `calcPercentage` is called reactively (`$:`) as well to make sure things are recalculated when `stats` changes.